# sql Match () Against unrecognized

Tags: mysql, sql, match, against

When I tried this query

```
SELECT name, cost FROM items WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('baby')
```

phpmyadmin gives me a warning that states:

```
Unrecognized keyword. (near "MATCH" at position 43)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 49)
Unexpected token. (near "name" at position 50)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 58)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "AGAINST" at position 60)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 68)
Unexpected token. (near "'baby'" at position 69)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 74)
```

and it still shows the correct result. When I tried another query:

```
SELECT fisrt_name , country FROM people WHERE MATCH (first_name) AGAINST ('marr')
```

It only gives me and error without getting result. Is there any mistakes that I did?

EDIT: I updated the phpmyadmin but what I got is new error message saying

```
 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

Comment: Presumably, you are not using MySQL, because that is a MySQL construct.

Comment: Added `mysql` tag based on the mentioning of "phpmyadmin"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE people ADD FULLTEXT people_first_name(first_name);
```

Try this to add a full text index on column first_name, and retry your query.

Comment: that worked thanks, another question do i need to use that query manually for every columns or any other way to Add fulltext at the beginning of creating tables ?

Comment: You need to add fulltext index only for columns, which need to be used in fulltext queries(with keyword "MATCH").

P.S. If my answer solves your probem, please accept it, that will be helpful for other users.

Comment: you can also check the link for further reference https://www.petefreitag.com/item/477.cfm